# How to use Dataset-based transformation in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a Spark job for Batch mode (using Datasets) which performs some transformation and ingests data into NOSQL.

I get data from other source which is similar in structure as received in batch mode albeit the frequency is very high (mins). Can I use the code I use for batch mode for Streaming?

I am trying to avoid 2 copy of code to deal with similar structure.

Comment: Please post more details - what you are doing, some code examples and Spark version. In Spark 2.0 you have Structured Streaming, so streaming Datasets are ready to use

Comment: From http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#overview: "Structured Streaming is still ALPHA in Spark 2.1 and the APIs are still experimental." which I read as "not for production use" / "know but don't use yet".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` streaming operator (as described in [the scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)):

```
transform[U](transformFunc: (RDD[T]) ⇒ RDD[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): DStream[U]
```

> Return a new DStream in which each RDD is generated by applying a function on each RDD of 'this' DStream.